# How to load custom packages from inside Django apps into views.py?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, python-3.x, django-views, three-tier

I am new to Django and have a little problem with making all the project structure clear and organized and so on.. The MVC stuff in Django is quite easy to use when making a small project. However, when I am trying to get a new layer (application logic, like three-tier architecture) between views.py and models.py I have problem to do so.

I have the following structure:

- mysite/

  - manage.py
  - app1/

    - models.py
    - views.py
    - logic/

      - __init__.py
      - Class1.py
      - parser.py
  - ...

and I want to load into `views.py` stuff from `Class1.py` and `parser.py`.
How do I do it?

Neither of the following works:

`from app1.logic import *`

`from app1.logic.Class1 import Class1`

Also, it would help me if somebody could list me some example of a really huge django project. It looks like either lots of classes and .py files should be in every app folder or everything is in the models.py.. Both look a little disorganised and I'm sure there is a way to make it a little bit clearer (like in Zend or Symfony).

And, I'm working with Python3 and Django 1.5b2.

Thanks.

Comment: if you have `__init__.py`, youshould be able to import it. Are you able to import it in the shell?

Comment: What is `screenshots`? Do you mean `mysite`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant app1... And in the shell I'm able to import it.. I think there could be problem with relative importing.. when I'm inside the app1, console can import the modules, but when django calls views through x other files/layers, the path is somehow changed or something.. Could be?

Answer (score 0):

If Class1 or parser import from views, then you have a circular dependency. You'll need to move any shared code out into a third file.

You might consider though whether you need all those separate files under `logic`. In Python there's no requirement to have a class in its own file, so maybe you could have a single `logic.py` instead of a logic directory containing several files.

Comment: Yup, I know that. But then I'd have in one `logic.py` huge huge number of classes and that's the "problem" I'm trying to solve.